# Custom JS breaks after page change in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've been working on my personal website and making it into a PWA using NextJS. Whenever I change pages from my app, the custom JS I have imported to the top level component (_document.js) stops working on the other pages unless I reload the page. Anyone have a solution to this or experiencing something similar?

Here's a link to a video I recorded showing what I'm talking about. I can also provide code if needed. I feel like this is a relatively easy fix, but it's my first attempt and Next and still getting used to the environment.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16doKPpJPDHhFcYLiX8lZEWGoTf8b19MM/view

```
//navbar.js (imported js file)
const menu = document.querySelector('#hamburger');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const drawer = document.querySelector('.navbar');

menu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  drawer.classList.toggle('open');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  drawer.classList.remove('open');
});
```

Comment: Provide a _minimal working_ code snippet, reproducing the issue you describe, preferable a [**Stack snippet**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Why are you manipulating the DOM outside of React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're think of a React app like a traditional (static) web app - one written in PHP or rendered via templates to HTML.

With React, it's an antipattern to manipulate the DOM independent of React.

In this particular case, a better approach would be a global state (you can use Redux, for example) to maintain the state of the menu drawer. Clicking the hamburger icon toggles this global state value and the drawer itself handles its classes itself (appending `open` if `state.open`).

Here's what your components would look like:

```
const Header = ({ toggleMenu }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <button onClick={ toggleMenu } />
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(null, { toggleMenu })(Header)

const Menu = ({ isOpen }) => {
  return (
    <div className={ isOpen ? "open" : "" }>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(function (state) {
  return { isOpen: state.menu.open }
})(Menu)
```

your action creator

```
function toggleMenu () {
  return { action: TOGGLE_MENU }
}
```

and your reducer

```
function menuReducer(previousState, action) {
  switch (action.action) {
    case TOGGLE_MENU:
      return { ...previousState: open: !previousState.open }
    default:
      return previousState
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer. You're right, I wasn't thinking in React-land. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Very good reason to implement Redux because I didn't think I would necessarily need it. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Tyler, could you take a look at my repo and tell me what I'm missing? I can't seem to figure out how to call actions within my components. https://github.com/nicer00ster/nicer00ster-blog

Comment: You're close. `toggleMenu` uses `action: "TOGGLE_MENU"` whereas your reducer uses `actionTypes.TOGGLE_MENU` which equals `TOGGLE`. Either change that to `TOGGLE_MENU` or the action created in `toggleMenu` to `TOGGLE`